# How to keep the format of workbook after saving without affecting the Layouts(tables, color, styles)

Tags: vba, excel

When some operation are done in workbook through VBA, and while saving it through VBA , the Tables, Clolors and Charts were not coming when i am trying to open the saved file.
i have created a chart for data from some workbook and it is working.
But if i save or saveas the workbook which has Chart, when i try to open again, no charts and tables and colors applied to some rows were not displaying, only plain data is displaying.

Source workbook is in .csv format.
I am saving it as .xlsx and .csv.

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\finaloutput11.csv"`
 `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`

or
 `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\finaloutput12.xlsx"`
 `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`
tried with only save option too.

Please tell how to keep the format too.

Comment: Start to examine the parameters for the [.SaveAs() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)

Comment: @mehow: You beat me this time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the relevant file format while saving the file.

See this table

```
51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsx)
52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsm)
50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)
56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls)
```

So your code will be written as

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
"C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\finaloutput12.xlsx", fileformat:=51
```

For csv, the file format is `6` so try this

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
"C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\finaloutput11.csv", fileformat:=6
```

Comment: Hi, If i paste the above code, Run time error-1004, application defined or object defined error. tried for '56' also. i have replaced this code in place of old code.

Comment: i have replaced this code in place of old code, i am using excel 2007 version.

Comment: Is the path correct? Because it works for me and the only time it gives me that error is when you give an incorrect path.